# How can I append modal button inside td using ajax script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I have problem inserting modal button inside my html table. I'm using AJAX and append built in function. I tried this approach

" Open modal"

but it did'nt work. I tried to remove the button properties like 'class', 'type' , etc and it worked but I need those. Any approach for this. Thank you.

This is my code

```
<script type=text/javascript>
      $(document).ready(function() {
       });
    
       function getData(id){
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
          $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET",
          url: "getproducts/",
          dataType: 'json',
           data: {id: id}, 
          success: function (response) {
            var len = 0;
            if(response['data'] !=null){
              len = response['data'].length;  
            }
           
            $('#userTable tbody').empty();
            if(len > 0){
              for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var p_id = response['data'][i].p_id;
                var p_name = response['data'][i].p_name;
                var p_amount = response['data'][i].p_amount;
                var m_fname = response['data'][i].m_fname;


                var tr_str = 
                "<tr>" +
                   "<td>" + p_id + "</td>"+
                   "<td>" + p_name + "</td>" +

                  //  HOW CAN I ADD MODAL BUTTON HERE THIS APPROACH DOESN'T WORKED
                   "<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" 
                     data-bs-target="#myModal2">Open modal</button></td>"                         
               
                "<tr>";

                $('#userTable tbody').append(tr_str); 
              }
            }
      
       }
       });
    };
    
  </script>
```

Expected output should be like this

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with string concatenation
I am giving a code. please replace it.

```
"<td> <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' 
                     data-bs-target='#myModal2'>Open modal</button></td>"
```